# Blank Output on For Loop in Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'd like to know how this script can have blank output for the aws_user_group variable. When the outer loop is looping on the values of the aws_groups array.

I use this line to create an array of the groups in an aws account:

```
readarray aws_groups < <(aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Groups[].GroupName')
```

And then I loop through that array. I loop through another array of aws_roles inside that loop.

With the aws_role loop in place, I get blank output on the aws_user_group while loop AFTER the last element of the aws_groups array is printed for that iteration:

Here's what the output from the script looks like, when it's missing the aws_group info:

```
Echo AWS Group: COMPANY_CSE from group while loop
Echo AWS Group: COMPANY_CSE from role while loop
*************************************************************
AWS User Name: tdunphy
AWS User Group: COMPANY_CSE
AWS Account: COMPANY-bill
AWS Account Number: 123456789101
*************************************************************
Echo AWS Group:  COMPANY_POWERUSERS from group while loop
Echo AWS Group:  COMPANY_POWERUSERS from role while loop
*************************************************************
AWS User Name: tdunphy
AWS User Group:  COMPANY_POWERUSERS
AWS Account: COMPANY-bill
AWS Account Number: 123456789101
*************************************************************
Echo AWS Group:  from group while loop
Echo AWS Group:  from role while loop
No user group or user role in this interation.
```

There are two members of that group array and then it prints that there is no group info on the final iteration of the loop.

If I remove the aws_role loop, then it doesn't print blank output for the aws_groups array. And everything lines up!

This is a stripped down version of my code that shows what I am doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws_key=lab
aws_users_all=all_users.txt
aws_account_num=123456789101
create_user_list() {
       while IFS= read -r aws_user_name
       do
       user_lives_here=$(aws iam get-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key" 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.User.UserName')
       if [[ -n "$user_lives_here" ]]; then
        readarray aws_groups < <(aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name "$aws_user_name" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Groups[].GroupName')
        readarray aws_roles < <(aws iam list-roles --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Roles[].RoleName')
        while IFS= read -r aws_user_group
        do
        echo "This is the AWS Group: $aws_user_group"
          echo "Echo AWS Group: $aws_user_group from group while loop"
          while IFS= read -r aws_role
          do
             echo "Echo AWS Group: $aws_user_group from role while loop"
             if [[ -z "$aws_role" ]]; then
              echo "Null role."
              continue 1
             fi
            sleep 10
            aws_user_has_role=$(aws iam get-role --role-name "$aws_role" --profile="$aws_key" | jq -r '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS' | sed "s/arn:aws:iam::832839043616:user\///g"  | grep "$aws_user_name")
            if [[ -n "$aws_user_has_role" ]]; then
              aws_user_role=$aws_role
              echo "Debug statement"
              printf "This is the user role name: %s\\nThis is the user name: %s\\nThis is the group: %s\\nThis is the account:%s\\n*" "$aws_user_role" "$aws_user_name" "$aws_user_group" "$aws_key"
              sleep 10
            fi
            if [[ -n "$aws_user_group" && -n "$aws_user_role" ]]; then
              printf "AWS User Name: %s\\nAWS User Group: %s\\nAWS User Role: %s\\nAWS Account: %s\\nAWS Account Number: %s\\n\\n" "$aws_user_name" "$aws_user_group" "$aws_user_role" "$aws_key" "$aws_account_num"
              break
              sleep 10
            elif [[ -n "$aws_user_group" ]]; then
              printf "AWS User Name: %s\\nAWS User Group: %s\\nAWS Account: %s\\nAWS Account Number: %s\\n\\n" "$aws_user_name" "$aws_user_group" "$aws_key" "$aws_account_num"
              break
            else
                printf "No user group or user role in this interation.\\n\\n"
            fi
          done  <<< "${aws_roles[@]}"
        done <<< "${aws_groups[@]}"
        else
           echo "User $aws_user_name does not exist in: $aws_key"
        fi
    echo
    echo
  done < "$aws_users_all"
}
```

How can I eliminate the empty group output after the last member of the aws_groups array is printed?

Comment: Surely you could try to build a [mcve] here? This is quite a wall of code -- ideally, you'd have something people could run themselves to reproduce, without needing `aws` accounts or even AWS-specific tools installed.

Comment: Also, `while read ... <<<"${aws_roles[@]}"` is, as an idiom, generally pretty silly. If you have something in an array, why would you concatenate the array into a string and read from the string, rather than just iterating over the array elements, as with `for role in "${aws_roles[@]}"`?

Comment: Ok, apologies. I will try again with less code.

Comment: ...consider using `declare -p arrayname` to print your arrays for debugging, *and* for purposes of building standalone reproducers -- if you can provide an array definition, then you can include that definition in your reproducer, so the command that may have generated that data originally is no longer needed.

Comment: If your content is in an array, and your goal is to iterate over that array's elements, a `for` loop is **definitely** more appropriate than a `while read` loop.

Comment: OK thank you very much. I will work on this and try to come back with a better example if I still need help at that point.

Comment: BTW, you should probably start using the `-t` argument to `readarray` when switching to a `for` loop.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for letting me know! ;)

Comment: '-t     Remove a trailing delim (default newline) from each line read.` SWEET!!! Thanks for the tip!